# Files at a custom dir in app/ not reloading in dev environment on Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration

I have created a new dir and subdirs in my project, just like the example below:

```
app/
--- services/
------ comments/
--------- create_comments_service.rb
```

but for every modification I make in 'create_comments_service.rb' I have to restart my server (in dev environment).

Is there anything I can do to do not have to restart my server every time I modify a file inside this dir/subdirs?

---

I had to add the following line in `config/application.rb` so Rails could recognize the files in my custom dir:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('app/services/**/*.rb')].each{|rb| require rb}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? It looks like you're fighting rails on functionality, and you could likely do what you need to do within rails conventions.

Comment: I want to store my database operations inside that folder.

Comment: What would you do in these files that you couldn't do from your controller, and/or model?

Comment: I am wanting to remove the db logic from the controllers. Keep them neat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I haven't enough points to make a comment, so I'll add an answer.

In Rails 5 all folders inside `app` are autoloaded. You can check if the needed subfolder is in the list:

```
bin/rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'
```

If you see `services/comments` in the output then maybe you need to stop your rails server, run `spring stop` an restart the server after it.
If you don't see - try to change the added line in `config/application.rb` to

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'services', '**/')]
```

And some words about helpers.I do not agree with Martin - helpers are more often used to move out view-related code.
But he is right, it is not a common practice to make a separate service for every controller action. What is in your `create_comments_service.rb`?

Comment: Hello, @Vasilisa! Sorry for the late reply! I do appreciate your comment. It was very helpful! :D. The main reason I created this folder  was to put my db operation related actions (as classes). I actually do not know if this is a good pattern. Do you have any other that you might suggest? Thank you again :D

Comment: Happy to help you, @AugustoCarmo :)  It is a good pattern for complicated things. For example, CommentsController#create: creates a comment to an article, sends an email to an article owner, creates some notifications and makes you a pizza. In this case it is a good idea to move all this complicate logic to the service. It would be easier to help if I could see your controller/service code :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you are fighting Rails conventions, and that will almost always be punishing.

If you want to keep your controllers neat, and not clutter them with verbose code, you should put that code in your Helper Methods.

Whenever you generate a controller, it will also generate a helper file. For example `rails g controller static` will create `app/helpers/static_helper.rb` Put your excess code here, and in your controller `include StaticHelper` and you will have all those features from your helper avaliable in your controller keeping it nice and clean.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would like to know if the suggestion you gave is the best practice when dealing with db operations. I was making each db operation a service class (like create, delete...)

Comment: It is my understanding that when dealing directly with database operations, such as `Comment.new` or `Comment.create` this should be done in the controller and/or helper. Service classes should usually be reserved for more complicated ruby.